# mswjs: Acquisition of certain data fails only once

Tags: javascript, axios, vite, msw

I am testing data usage of API with msw.

The problem is such as the following handler:

```
export const users =
    rest.get("http://localhost:8080" + reqUserPath, (req, res, ctx) => {
        const data: userType[] = [
            {
                id: '1',
                name: "foo",
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                name: 'dog',
            },
        ];
        return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(data));
    })
;
```

When accessing this URL, two types of errors will be displayed on the console.

`Reason: CORS request did not succeed`

`AxiosError ERR_NETWORK`

However, if you hot-reload the app, the data will be successfully retrieved and displayed.

If I start up the api server and db server and test the connection, no problems occur.

Also, other handlers work fine.

I don't understand why this happens.

I get the same error if I port this handler to PATH for a simple function for testing.

Comment: If you're getting CORS errors your browser is not finding the headers it expects and you need to update your sever.

Comment: Development servers are usually more permissive, that is why you don't have CORS errors during development.

Comment: Problem is nothing to do with solidjs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm solved.
First of all, the CORS error was a browser problem.
After changing from firefox to chrome, the error disappeared.
And about AxiosError.
This was happening because I had a createResource that retrieved data in a global location in solidjs.
Therefore, the fetch was performed before msw started, causing a problem.
I created createSignal to control the fetch timing and registered it as a fetcher in createResource, and it started working properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).